# Can't import rest_framework on Windows but can on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've never used Django Rest Framework, but I'm trying to learn it. After installing it with

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

I tried importing the serializer module into a random module using

```
from rest_framework import serializer
```

This brings up a pylint error - no module found -  when I use it in VScode on Windows 10, but I tried it on Ubuntu and it worked perfectly fine. I have no idea why the python interpreter can't find it when using Windows. I checked the site-packages folder and it was in there. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling djangorestframework to make sure I had the latest version. Nothing works on Windows. Anyone know what the issue could be? I appreciate any help.

Comment: The pip command didn't gave any error? I suspect you have multiple versions of idle installed in your pc?

Comment: no pip didn't give any errors and I don't believe I have multiple versions of idle installed. how would I check to see if I do?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that I actually did have 2 different versions of Python installed on my computer, a 32bit and 64bit version. I'm guessing this was confusing the interpreter. After uninstalling the 32bit version everything seems to be working fine.